# jQuery version 1.7.2 versus 1.8.3

Tags: jquery

I am using this jQuery line of code and it works fine with jQuery version 1.7.2 installed

```
$("div[id='gallery-'+nr] ul.previews li[id*='preview-']").last().clone().attr('id','preview-extra').appendTo("div[id='gallery-'+nr] ul.previews");
```

I am adding a `<li>`-element to an `<ul>` list
Unfortunately this line of code doesn't work in jQuery 1.8.3

The errormessage is 
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[id='gallery-'+nr]  ul.previews
Bronbestand: http://www.inwording.nl/supportbeta/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3
Regel: 2

So it relates to the appendTo part of the code.

I can change it to

```
.appendTo("div[id='gallery-'+nr] ul[class='previews']");
```

This removes the errormessage, but doesn't add the element to my list.

I can change the jQuery version back to 1.7.2 but I am not sure that is the way to go as this is part of a WordPress plugin, and WordPress 3.5+ comes with jQuery 1.8.3. Other plugins may depend on 1.8.3, if I change it back to 1.7.2 it will break the other plugins.

I tried to find the differences between 1.7.2 and 1.8.3 but couldn't find any information that related to the code I use.

Has anyone seen this problem before?

Comment: What exactly does `div[id='gallery-'+nr]` refer to? Is `nr` a variable defined earlier in the code, so you are expecting something like `gallery-123`?

Comment: you have to put quotes around the attribute value.

Comment: You realise that even v1.8 is out of date by two major releases (current version is 1.10)

Comment: In case it isn't clear: `[id='gallery-'+nr]` is an invalid expression. Apparently, that got fixed after 1.7.2.

Comment: @Spudley There is no use for installing the newest jQuery version if the system you are adding a plugin in to (WordPress 3.5.1) comes with an earlier version by default.

Answer (score 1):

Is `nr` a variable that you're using to paste together a selector, or is it actually part of the `id` of your `<div>`?

In other words, is this what's in the HTML code?

```
<div id="gallery-+nr">
```

That's an unusual `id`, but it is valid in HTML5.

If that's what it is, then the problem is just that one of the quotes is in the wrong place in this selector:

```
div[id='gallery-'+nr]
```

That would need to be:

```
div[id='gallery-+nr']
```

The first version is an invalid selector, and even jQuery 1.7.2 rejects when you use it by itself:

```
> $("div[id='gallery-'+nr]")
  Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [id='gallery-'+nr]
```

Oddly enough, 1.7.2 *does* allow this selector when it's used as part of the longer selector in your code:

```
> $("div[id='gallery-'+nr] ul[class='previews']")
  [ ul.previews ]
```

The error checking got stricter in 1.8.3, where it rejects this form of the selector too. But again changing it to this would work:

```
$("div[id='gallery-+nr'] ul[class='previews']")
```

Now when I first read your question I thought `nr` was actually a variable that should be concatenated into an `id` string in the selector, e.g. you may have this HTML:

```
<div id="gallery-9">
    <ul class="previews">
    </ul>
</div>
```

and given a variable `nr` whose current value is 9, you could select the `<ul>` like this:

```
$( "div[id='gallery-" + nr + "'] ul[class='previews']" )
```

I suspect that I was wrong in this guess, since you mentioned that the code worked in jQuery 1.7.2. But just in case, I'll leave this part of the answer here with a couple of related suggestions:

1. It works OK either way, but I would suggest swapping the single and double quotes around, so the JavaScript strings are single quoted and the attributes inside the selectors are double quoted. This way it follows the jQuery documentation for selectors and is also consistent with your other quoted strings.
2. It's helpful to format long jQuery chains with the method calls on separate lines instead of one long line.

Putting all this together, the code might look like:

```
$( '#gallery-' + nr + ' ul.previews li[id*="preview-"]' )
    .last()
    .clone()
    .attr( 'id', 'preview-extra' )
    .appendTo( 'div[id="gallery-' + nr + '"] ul.previews' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately there is an error in your code. Guess even when you follow the rules on quotes it can still be confusing. `div[id="gallery-' + nr + ']` should be `div[id="gallery-' + nr + '"]` It is really great so many people are willing to share their knowledge, however I think most of the posters can do without the patronizing.

Comment: @RST - Thanks for catching that. Yes, pasting together strings where the strings themselves contain quotes is always confusing, no matter what convention you follow! :-) With regard to the patronizing, I wasn't clear, were you referring to something in my answer, or just SO answers in general? I try to make my answers friendly as well as helpful, so when I miss the mark it's useful to know the specifics so I can fix it. I looked through my answer closely and found a couple of things that could have come across as unfriendly and updated it. Any feedback would be welcome.

Comment: @RST - And also, which did it turn out to be? Is `nr` a variable that should be concatenated with other strings to make the selector, or is it a literal part of the `id`?

Comment: nr is a variable. So the last part of your answer is correct. All I was missing is the `+nr+`construction. I stated that the code works correctly in 1.7.2. there is no need to burn it down to "this code may have done something in an earlier version". The plugin does a lot more than that.

Comment: @RST - If `nr` is a variable, then the code in your question would not have picked up the value of that variable in 1.7.2 or any version of jQuery. Where `nr` appears in the selector, it is literal text in a quoted string, not a variable reference. This would not be affected in any way by the jQuery version, because it's basic JavaScript code parsing that is independent of jQuery or any other code libraries. And jQuery doesn't look inside the selector for strings that might be variable names, it just uses the text you give it.